# Formatting a transformRequest - Angular to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm trying to do create an add function from my Angular app and my PHP back-end. I'm trying to parse what I'm sending to the server with a transformationRequest but I'm not entirely sure what format matches the $_POST[] in PHP - does anyone have an idea what's going wrong here? The object sends to the server but comes back with the err status.

app.js:

```
$scope.addUser = function(){
    var data = $scope.tempUserData;

    $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: 'http://localhost:8080/sns/addUser.php',
               data: data,
               headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
               },
               transformRequest: function (data) {
                   transformedData="";
                   keys=Object.keys(data);values=Object.values(data);
                   for (i in keys)
                        transformedData+=keys[i]+"="+values[i]+"&"; 
                   return transformedData;
             }
            }).success(function(response){
                if(response.status == 'OK'){
                $scope.users.push({
                    id:response.data.id,
                    name:response.data.name,
                    email:response.data.email,
                    phone:response.data.phone,
                    group:response.data.group
                });
            }
            $scope.tempUserData = {};
        });
};
```

addUser.php:

```
<?php
include 'DB.php';
$db = new DB();
$tblName = 'members';
            if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
                $userData = array(
                    'name' => $_POST['data']['name'],
                    'email' => $_POST['data']['email'],
                    'phone' => $_POST['data']['phone'],
                    'group' => $_POST['data']['group']
                );
                $insert = $db->insert($tblName,$userData);
                if($insert){
                    $data['data'] = $insert;
                    $data['status'] = 'OK';
                    $data['msg'] = 'User data has been added successfully.';
                }else{
                    $data['status'] = 'ERR';
                    $data['msg'] = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                }
            }else{
                $data['status'] = 'ERR';
                $data['msg'] = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
            }
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Console output with updated transformRequest:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE8Xe.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
transformRequest:function(obj) {
            var str =[];
    for(var p in obj){
str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) +"=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]))

                }
        return str.join("&");
            }
```

And you should use `then` instead `success` . The deprecated `.success` and `.error` methods have been removed from AngularJS 1.6.

Comment: I replaced my transformRequest with yours but I'm still getting the same error from the PHP - thanks for the tip on the success method by the way.

Comment: @StolenSheep Can you open tab network in chrome dev tool , and post img data sending in it

Comment: I added the img of the output to the original post above. It gets the status 'OK' indicating the data has been inserted, but when I look at the database it's clearly not been added, and the response that's supposed to be used to push the new entry to the list of users is undefined too. I'm lost to be honest..!

Comment: I'm not sure about your code in php . But code in angular seems fine . And reason why users is underfine because you lost `data` .If you use then you should change to    `id:response.data.data.id` @StolenSheep